# LocalStorage Function Insert, Edit Json

Tags: javascript, json

I've created a function to add data to local storage, but it only seems to work once. After that my json gets odd back slashes which makes it inaccessible.

I want to set a data every time they hit the website site, for instant date, page visit etc. First off, I'm trying to get date to set on each page load.

**First Visit** 
[image: First visit]

**Change Page**

The json turns into the following making it unreadable.

> "{\"date\":\"2014-04-03\"}"

**Functions**

```
   setData(elmbrent, 1, "date", today);


   function setData(u, c, k, v) {
       var copy =  localStorage[u + c];
       if(copy == undefined){
          copy = {};
       }
       copy[k] = v;
       localStorage.setItem(u + c, JSON.stringify(copy));   
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten JSON.parse. Something like this:

```
function setData(u, c, k, v) {
   var copy =  JSON.parse(localStorage[u + c] || "{}");
   copy[k] = v;
   localStorage.setItem(u + c, JSON.stringify(copy));   
}
```